# Django migration relation does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I'm trying to run the initial migrations on a django app and when I try to run the migrate command (python manage.py migrate or makemigrations) I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "dotworks_server_internship" does not exist
LINE 1: ...s", "dotworks_server_internship"."questions" FROM "dotworks_...
                                                             ^
```

I'm on a Windows environment using Django 1.9.6 and my database is postgres. Plus, I'm using PGAdmin to manage my database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dotworks',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypasswordgoeshere',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

I had this problem and I had to comment out everything in `urls.py` that referenced `views.py`, then run `makemigrations`.

Comment: When you run python manage.py makemigrations, it seems to check urls.py (and in my case, urls_tenanats.py) and will attempt to execute sql to read model data before the data exists. When I run makemigrations, it fails on the first model with relation XXX does not exist. I commented out the code in urls.py that referenced views.py and the makemigrations worked.

Comment: This is a very strange gotcha that does not seem to be documented ANYWHERE! saved me hours of pulling my hair out. SO to the rescue once again!

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you don't have any class variables in your code that are calling Django manager

For example:

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    se = SomeEntity.objects.first()  # fetching some entity on the class level

    def list(self, request):
    # the rest of the code
```

So, when you try to create/apply migrations, this variable will also try to initialise, and will try to access `SomeEntity`, but at that moment that entity doesn't even exist, and the error occurs.

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to migrate particular app using following process. Refer [Django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/)

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Initial migration created then run migrate command with app name

```
python manage.py migrate appname1, appname2
```

Answer (score 3):

If all other solutions mentioned fail, if you are still in development probably the easiest solution is dropping the database (in pgAdmin 4 2.0, right-click on database) and then run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: What if you are dealing with production DB? Can simply delete it?

Answer (score 3):

When you run a query before applying migrations this error appears.

If you got this error during `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py migrate` you must consider that `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands run after successful django bootstrap! So this error happens when you run a query during django bootstrap! So you must find the place you run this query during bootstrap progress.

For example, during bootstrap, django reads root `{project}/urls.py` and its nested imports. If you use views or viewsets in urls.py and they are run a query during initializing (in their `__init__` method or `__init__.py`file or somewhere etc.), it happens!

In this situation and similars, you must comment out any entry in urls.py and similar files which cause running a query during bootstrap and prevent them from running by raising of exception during bootstrap! `makemigrations` and `migrate` need successful bootstrap to be run!

If your commented out code needs to `makemigrations` and `migrate` handcooks :D, it needs to be patient and be silent for a cycle or a while ;), and after a successful migrations it could be active and verbose ;D.

Comment: I have created a custom package in django only, now when I installed it in other django project it gives me the same error and during trackbacking the error, the line to comment out was showing me in the site-packages folder. What to do in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Your app is trying to call some DB entries that does not exist.
If you are trying to migrate it to a new database, one of your options is to **export a dump of old database and import it to your new DB**.

For example in PostgreSQL, import the database using below command then migration will work!

```
sudo -u postgres -i psql mydb < mydb-export.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Django is running an optional check. Pass the `--skip-checks` flag in your call to `manage.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in local, 
For each Django app (maybe you have only one), erase the content of the `migrations` folder.
Then, run `python manage.py makemigrations app1 app2 app3` (if you have 3 Django apps named app1, app2, app3). This will (re)create the migrations files required to migrate your database

Then, run `python manage.py migrate`. It will apply the migration files you just created.

Comment: Didn't work, the problem seems to be that the tables are not even being created by the first migration attempt

Answer (score 0):

This error may be related to previous database error. So if you created a new database and you also face that type of error, you can simply run the command with the app name:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <"app name">
python manage.py migrate <"app name">
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove all urls from urls.py.

Create simple function view for viewing nothing:

```
def simple(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

and add urls to urls.py

do migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

after migrate, recover the deleted urls.py contents

Answer (score 0):

For me the error came from some initialization code I put into the app.ready() method. Commenting that part of code allowed me to run the command makemigrations without any issue.

I believe app.ready is called at some point by manage.py even for the makemigrations command, which caused my code to query my database before any migration.

I found the problematic code thanks to the traceback.